# Calculating total resistance

Tags: resistors, resistance, parallel, series

How do we calculate the total resistance from A to B R1||(R2+R3) but the same can be said for R2 so how does it work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn4iq5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hint: This circuit is symmetric, so no current will flow through the resistor in the middle.

Comment: This is a bridge. It's either balanced or unbalanced, depending on the resistor values.

Comment: You should be able to answer this yourself. Look up for balanced wheatstone bridge.

Comment: @JunSeo-He Do you know how to convert two resistors and a voltage source into their Thevenin equivalent of one voltage source and just one resistor value?

Answer (score 0):

R1 is not parallel with R2 + R3. You should look up the definition. There are ways to connect components other than serial and parallel.  If you'd never heard the terms you should still be able to handle serial and parallel connections without cookbook formulas by judicious application of Ohm's Law. You can do the same with other connections. The comments so far should lead you to the simple solution.